# WordPress Media Uploader with size select

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, plugins

I want to add an image input to my own WordPress plugin.
For that I use the standard WordPress media-uploader like so:

```
var custom_uploader;

$('.upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
    input = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Collage Image',
        library: {
            type: 'image'
        },
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Collage Image'
        },
        multiple: false,

        displaySettings: true,

        displayUserSettings: false
    });

    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        input.prev('input').val(attachment.url);
    });

    custom_uploader.open();

});
```

This works perfect.
I add two more image sizes that were exact for my plugin:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'collage-large', 460, 660, true );
    add_image_size( 'collage-small', 460, 325, true );
}
```

My problem:
The selector for the image size or better the thumbnail selector is not shown at the media upload form. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the media insertion dialog as shown on the "edit page" site, which adds *alignment*, *link_to* and *size* input fields. To do so add `frame: 'post'` to your options array:

```
file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Select a image to upload',
    button: {
        text: 'Use this image',
    },
    multiple: false,
    frame:    'post',    // <-- this is the important part
    state:    'insert',
});
```

Instead of listening to the "select" event listen to the "insert" event. This code shows how retrieve the additional properties including the size:

```
// When an image is inserted, run a callback.
file_frame.on( 'insert', function(selection) {
    var state = file_frame.state();
    selection = selection || state.get('selection');
    if (! selection) return;
    // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
    var attachment = selection.first();
    var display = state.display(attachment).toJSON();  // <-- additional properties
    attachment = attachment.toJSON();
    // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
    var imgurl = attachment.sizes[display.size].url;
    jQuery( '#filenameFromURL' ).val( imgurl );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I find some where in Internet. May be it useful.

```
attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
```

With attachment you can working with:

1. alt
2. author
3. caption
4. compat ( <-- It is Object )

   - item
   - meta
5. date
6. dateFormatted
7. description
8. editLink
9. filename
10. height
11. icon
12. id
13. link
14. menuOrder
15. mime
16. modified
17. name
18. nonces ( <-- thi is object)

    - delete
    - update
    - **proto**
19. orientation
20. sizes  ( <-- this is object)

    - full  ( <-- this is object)

      - height
      - orientation
      - url
      - width
      - **proto**
    - medium ( <-- this is object)

      - height
      - orientation
      - url
      - width
      - **proto**
    - thumbnail  ( <-- this is object)

      - height
      - orientation
      - url
      - width
      - **proto**
    - **proto**  ( <-- this is object)
21. status
22. subtype
23. title
24. type
25. uploadedTo
26. url
27. width

To solve your problem I suggest use with case 20 above:

```
input.prev('input').val(attchment.sizes.collage-large.url);
```

Hope this work!

Answer (score 3):

You're VERY close. To make the size selectable within the admin panel, review the [add_image_size Codex Entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#For_Media_Library_Images_.28Admin.29):

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'your-custom-size' => __('Your Custom Size Name'),
    ) );
}
```

So in your case, this should do what you need:

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'collage-large' => __('Collage Large'),
        'collage-small' => __('Collage Small'),
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this was my next question ;)
But my problem still exists! The section where I can select the thumnails isn´t there !